# how do I get a specific value from XML with same names

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to get the value for one of the branches in the below screenshot - the value is `<ParamValue>` with the blue arrow.

The problem is that there are so many brances with the same name and I think the only way I want to filter them is on the name (don't want to do CommandID that that might chnage in the future) - so, `PackageName="intel_teaming_script.ps1"`.

How can I do this? I tried the below but it does not show anything back:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-content C:\temp\build.xml
    $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Phases/Phase/Package[@PackageName='intel_teaming_script']")
    $node.PackageName
```

I also tried this and still not getting it:

```
$findxml = $xml.Phases.Phase.Package | Where-Object {$_.PackageName -eq 'intel_teaming_script.ps1'}
$findxml.PackageName
```

Even if I do the above I still need to dig down and get the value out - which is a IP address.

Screenshot of XML below:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Based on @har07 answer which works the below is what I get as an answer:

```
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Phases/Phase/Package[@PackageName='intel_teaming_script.ps1']//ParamValue")

ParamValue

#text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
1.1.1.1
```

If I try converting it to a String and then using ExpandProperty I still get ParamValue listed..any idea how I can just get the IP address?

```
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Phases/Phase/Package[@PackageName='intel_teaming_script.ps1']//ParamValue")
$node.ToString()
$node | select -ExpandProperty "#text"
```

Result:

```
ParamValue
1.1.1.1
```

Comment: So, from the `<Package>` node having specific `PackageName`, you only want the first `<ParamValue>` or all of them? BTW, package name in the xpath lacks "`.ps1`" to match the one in screenshot

Comment: Correct - just the first one for starters - <ParamValue> - I would then put that into a variable and use it somewhere else in my script. I then have to proceed and get the others - I think once I know how to get the first one then I can work out the rest...hopefully!...and yes, apologise, I missed out the ".ps1" - still does not work if I include it.

Comment: Try this simplified one : `//Package[@PackageName='intel_teaming_script.ps1']//ParamValue`. `SelectSingleNode()` should, by default, return the first matched node

Comment: Tried that - like this: `$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Package[@PackageName='intel_teaming_script.ps1']//ParamValue.SelectSingleNode()")`........got this error: `Exception calling "SelectSingleNode" with "1" argument(s): "'//Package[@PackageName='intel_teaming_script.ps1']//ParamValue.SelectSingleNode()' has an invalid token."
At line:13 char:1
+ $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Package[@PackageName='intel_teaming_script.ps1'` ...

Comment: Sorry, my comment must've been confusing. Remove `SelectSingleNode()` from your xpath. The last part of my previous comment meant, by using `SelectSingleNode()` method (instead of `SelectNodes()`) you would get first matched node

Comment: Yes! - that worked. I updated the Question - could you take a look please? I want to only get the IP address but I am also getting "ParamValue" - any idea how I can just get the IP address. Also, am now wondering how I can get the second value and third etc....?

Comment: No - I made a mistake...I am getting the IP address only....just need to figure out how to get second, third etc values now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get element by position index in xpath, for example :

```
//Phases/Phase/Package[@PackageName='intel_teaming_script.ps1']//Param[2]/ParamValue
```

Above xpath return the *2nd* `<ParamValue>` found. Note that xpath position index starts from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: hmm...that is returning empty (null) for some reason - it contains the subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 - not too sure why it is NULL though? `$SubnetMask = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Phases/Phase/Package[@PackageName='intel_teaming_script.ps1']//ParamValue[2]")` - I also tried others [3], [4] etc and they are all NULL

Comment: figured it out...there are multiple PARAM in the nodes - so selecting the second PARAM gives the value I needed...`$SubnetMask = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Phases/Phase/Package[@PackageName='intel_teaming_script.ps1']//Param[2]/ParamValue")` Thanks A LOT for the help - appreciate it a lot!